# Sum Disappearing After Expectation

Tags: probability

I am trying to follow the algebra from the [book](http://www.researchandmarkets.com/reports/2329378/volatility_trading__website_2nd_edition_wiley.pdf) *Volatility Trading* by Sinclair, pg. 137. In one derivation where his eventual goal is to derive the famous Kelly formula, he starts by defining $X_n$ which gives the result of $n$'th trade (win or loss coming from a probability distribution) and a payoff $g(X_n)$ that maps those outcomes to another value, i.e. a win might bring \$2 a loss only \$1, and $f$ is the fraction of wealth invested at each round. $X_i$ is i.i.d. After a sequence of $n$ trades the wealth is at

$$ W_n = W_0 \prod_{i=1}^n (1+fg(X_i)) $$

He takes the log for an optimization he is about to do,

$$ \ln(W_n) = W_0 \sum_{i=1}^n \ln (1+fg(X_i))  $$

Fine so far. But here is the part I do not understand. He applies the expectation operator

$$ E[\ln(W_n)] = n W_0 E[\ln (1+fg(X_n))]  $$

Where did the sum go? The expectation somehow took the place of the sum?

Thanks,

Comment: Since the $X_i$ are iid, $E[\ln (1+fg(X_i))]=E[\ln (1+fg(X_n))]$ for all $i$. So $E[W_0\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (1+fg(X_i))] = W_0\sum_{i=1}^n E[\ln (1+fg(X_i))] = n\times W_0 E[\ln (1+fg(X_n))].$

Comment: "The expectation somehow took the place of the sum?" Not at all. Actually the authors probably write something similar to $$ E[\ln(W_n)] = E[\ln(W_0)]+\sum_{k=1}^n E[\ln (1+fg(X_k))]= E[\ln(W_0)]+n E[\ln (1+fg(X_1))].$$ Which step is unclear?